# can't use add() in array list or make "String arrays"

Tags: arrays, arraylist

```java
import java.util.*;

public class Player {
    
    

    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>(); // Create an ArrayList object
    paths.add("src/images/pacman.png");
    paths.add("src/images/pacmanUp.png");

    // constructor and other methods
}
```

it says "cannot resolve symbol add" and I don't know what I'm missing here, I have trouble even making a simple array of Strings and then putting stuff in it:

`String[] paths =new String[4];`
`paths[0]="HEY";`  --> "paths is not a defined class"

I have tryed changing all the imports but i can't werap my head around this, everything works just fine in all the other classes and rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're trying to call a method (add) on your ArrayList at the class level, outside of any method or constructor. This is not allowed in Java. The call to add should be inside a method or constructor.

Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
import java.util.*;
```

public class Player {

```
ArrayList<String> paths; // Declare the ArrayList object

public Player() {
    paths = new ArrayList<String>(); // Initialize the ArrayList
    paths.add("src/images/pacman.png"); // Now you can add items
    paths.add("src/images/pacmanUp.png");
}

// other methods }
```

In this code, I've moved the add calls into the constructor of the Player class. Now, whenever you create a new Player object, it will initialize the paths ArrayList and add the two strings to it.

As for the issue with the array, the error message "paths is not a defined class" suggests that there might be a syntax error in your code, or  that you are trying to use paths in a context where a class name is expected.